# How can I split the following string into an array that I can use to populate a html table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a string that looks like:

```
var str = '{ "abc": {
            "decline_reason": "Business rule switched off"
        },
        "def": {
            "decline_reason": "No response by interface"
        },
        "ghi": {
            "decline_reason": "Requested incorrect size" }';
```

I would like to split that string into an array that I can use to populate a table on a webpage.  I intend to use the initial reference ('abc'), with the reason ('Business rule switched off') on row 1, initial reference ('def'), with the reason ('No response by interface') on row 2, etc...

I have tried regex to break it down, and I've managed to find one that removes quotes, but not to break the string down.

I intend to populate the table with code like:

```
<table id="declinesTable">
            <tr>
                <th onclick="sortTable(0)">Reference Code</th>
                <th>Decline Reason</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="lender1">
                <td id="lender1"><script>document.getElementById("lender1").innerHTML = declines[0];</script>
                </td>
                <td id="declineReason1"><script>document.getElementById("declineReason1").innerHTML = declines[2];</script>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

skipping out the value "decline_reason" from the table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your string is in JSON format; rather than trying to tackle it with regex I'd strongly suggest `JSON.parse()` to convert it into an object

Comment: On closer look, it's _almost_ in JSON format; it's malformed (missing a trailing `}`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things - your string is missing a final }. Not sure where you're getting the string from, but it's in JSON format, so use JSON.parse to get it into an object, then iterate over the object to do something with each individual nested object. I would strongly recommend using a library like jQuery to help you append it to the table. You can google and very quickly find out how to add jQuery to your project. See below.

```js
function stringParse(str) {
  const json = JSON.parse(str);
  const html = Object.entries(json).reduce((h, [k, v]) => 
    h += `<tr><td>${k}</td><td>${v.decline_reason}</td></tr>`
  , "");

  $('#declinesTable').append(html);
}


const str = '{ "abc": {"decline_reason": "Business rule switched off"},"def": {"decline_reason": "No response by interface"},"ghi": {"decline_reason": "Requested incorrect size"}}'
stringParse(str);
```

```html
<table id="declinesTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Reference Code</th>
    <th>Decline Reason</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Spot on. Avoid keeping data as raw string as much as possible. As soon as the data enters your system you should be trying to unmarshall it to something.

Comment: Again and again:https://learn.jquery.com/performance/append-outside-loop/

Comment: Did not know this. I'll edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @kdsprogrammer also `Object.entries(items).forEach(([k, v]) => {})` or rather use `.reduce()` like: `const TRs = Object.entries(items).reduce((h, [k, v]) => { h += \`<tr><td>${k}</td><td>${v}</td></tr>\`;}, "");` and than just: `$('#declinesTable').append(TRs)`;

Comment: That output when I run the code snippet is absolutely perfect!!  when I've put the code directly onto the page, I'm seeing an error of "Uncaught referenceError: $ is not defined", and that is referring to the line with the 'append(html);' on it.  I'm not sure what that refers to as I literally copy/pasted, so that I can try it

Comment: @Steve_G you need to attach the jQuery library to your project. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Really sorry kdsprogrammer - I had added but, but not saved and it hadn't updated!!!  Your solution works perfectly!  Thank you so much - genuinely, I've spent 3 days Googling, trying different things and getting so frustrated with it all.  I really appreciate your time and help, and Roko too - many thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm looking at using a much larger json with lots of reasons (for lots of references).  When I expand the string 'str', it breaks the code - I'm not sure, but I think it may be due to line breaks??  is there a way to make the code ignore those?

Comment: @Steve_G what do you mean "expand the string" ?

Comment: The source of the string is postman output.  I only put 3 examples of the data row on the question, but I’m copying maybe 25-30 rows of data from postman.  Manual copy/paste, but the data runs down the page, rather than on one line.  This seems to break the code, but if I remove line breaks (or spaces), so the data is on one long line, it works.

Comment: @Steve_G why not just make the call to your API using JavaScript inside your app? Then you don’t need to mess with parsing it at all, you’ll just get it as JSON.

Comment: @kdsprogrammer I'm not going to lie, that is beyond me - it would be a better solution, but I don't believe I have the skills to put that together.  I've managed to apply a regex to the output so that I can copy/paste the output into a file, which displays in the table as intended.  I cannot thank you enough for your help - I wouldn't have got to this stage without your help!

Comment: @kdsprogrammer how would I amend your script so that it looks at a .json file for the decline_reason ?  It can be a local file (same folder), for example: response.json